# SoapClient - Recursively get rid of BOGUS tag generated in request

Tags: php, soap

I'm very surprised that this issue isn't more prevalent, but there are only a few answers to this in Google. And those are very specific to one single request where the solution is to manually tweak the structure of the Soap params before sending. I'll start by making it clear that I am working on a central gateway for multiple service calls. The only thing these calls have in common is that they pass the central method a multidim array of params. The central method then makes the SoapClient call.

I can structure the arrays individually if needed. I cannot build individual Soap param objects as suggested [here](http://www.fischco.org/blog/2011/3/26/php-soapserver-objects-arrays-and-encoding.html).

I have the following array in this instance:

```
Array
(
    [userId] => 336790
    [locationId] => 47862
    [schedule] => Array
        (
            [cipTime] => 15
            [confirmed] => 1
            [cycle] => Twice per Day
            [periods] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [WS_Period] => Array
                                (
                                    [duration] => 300
                                    [startTime] => 15
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [WS_Period] => Array
                                (
                                    [duration] => 240
                                    [startTime] => 870
                                )

                        )

                )

            [startDate] => 16-08-2014
        )

)
```

I am trying to create a recursive function to loop this array and build a valid Soap request object.

```
// Encode the params array into a format that the soap client can use.
    // This is to avoid the dreaded <BOGUS> tags that the PHP SoapClient generates in the request.
    private function encodeSoapParams(Array $params) {

        // The entire request should be an array
        $request = array();

        foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
            if(is_scalar($value)) {
                $request[$name] = new SoapVar($value, XSD_STRING, null, null, $name);
            } elseif(is_array($value)) {
                $newValue = $this->encodeSoapParams($value);
                $request[$name] = new SoapVar($newValue, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, $name);       
            }
        }

        return $request;
    }
```

Which works fine for the most part, except where we get to periods numeric array. (collection of two numerically indexed items in the above array). What I end up with in the request XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:Blah/WebService/">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:updateSchedule>
            <userId>336790</userId>
            <locationId>47862</locationId>
            <schedule>
                <cipTime>15</cipTime>
                <confirmed>1</confirmed>
                <cycle>Twice per Day</cycle>
                <periods>
                    <BOGUS>
                        <WS_Period>
                            <duration>300</duration>
                            <startTime>15</startTime>
                        </WS_Period>
                    </BOGUS>
                    <BOGUS>
                        <WS_Period>
                            <duration>240</duration>
                            <startTime>870</startTime>
                        </WS_Period>
                    </BOGUS>
                </periods>
                <startDate>16-08-2014</startDate>
            </schedule>
        </ns1:updateSchedule>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This is almost correct. If only the `<BOGUS>` level tags were completely omitted. As it stands the service is complaining about the structure (and I have no control over the service)

Any ideas on how I could get my recursive function to recognize collections like this? Really I think this is more of a logic challenge than a Soap-specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely this problem is dependant on individual array structure, but the following recursive function worked for me with every array I threw at it:

```
// Encode the params array into a format that the soap client can use.
    // This is to avoid the dreaded <BOGUS> tags that the PHP SoapClient generates in the request.
    // All PI call param arrays should pass through here first
    private function encodeSoapParams(Array $params) {

        // The entire request should be an array
        $request = array();

        foreach($params as $name => $value) {
            if(is_scalar($value)) {
                $request[$name] = new SoapVar($value, XSD_STRING, null, null, $name);
            } else {
                if($this->IsArrayAllKeyInt($value)) {
                    $collection = array();

                    foreach($value as $key => $itemVal) {
                        //$collection[] = $itemVal;
                        if(is_scalar($itemVal)) {
                            $collection[] = new SoapVar($itemVal, XSD_STRING, null, null, $name);
                        } else {
                            // We have an array
                            $subKey = key($itemVal);
                            $collection[] = new SoapVar($itemVal[$subKey], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, key($itemVal));
                        }
                    }
                    $request[$name] = new SoapVar($collection,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null, $name);
                } else {
                    $newValue = $this->encodeSoapParams($value);
                    $request[$name] = new SoapVar($newValue, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, $name);
                }
            }
        }

        return $request;
    }

// See if a given array has all Int keys.
// See encodeSoapParams()
function IsArrayAllKeyInt($InputArray)
{
    if(!is_array($InputArray))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(count($InputArray) <= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return array_unique(array_map("is_int", array_keys($InputArray))) === array(true);
}
```

Comment: How to implemented this feature, Kindly guide me ..?
Or Update the full code.